# Eclipse Throws Weird ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

Apparently, Eclipse can't find a class from within said class. Here is my error (for some reason, Stack Overflow doesn't like the formatting on here): http://paste.ubuntu.com/686811/

Here is my main method: http://paste.ubuntu.com/686812/

It was fine for a long time, but all of a sudden, it broke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have the EscapeComponent lib in your build path you don't export it in runtime.

Go to project properties, "Java Build Path" option, "Order and Export" tab and make sure that the lib that holds EscapeComponent is selected. 
Otherwise it won't be available in runtime and so NoClassFoundException happens.

Comment: There is no lib, but there is an Escape/src (Escape is my project name). If you want the project, here it is: https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=CD536BD0008E28F2&id=CD536BD0008E28F2%21120

Comment: Well, I downloaded, imported to eclipse and run succesfully. There is nothing wrong in it. Perhaps your project has gone mad :P Try to delete it and import it again... (yes like turning off and turning on :Px10)
Lastly,you should add this sentence in your frame: `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` in order your app terminate when the window is closed

Comment: Ok, I had that, but I think that I tried a regular Frame, so I removed it. I think that might be it.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse determine if the EscapeComponent is in your build path. An easy way to do this is by going to the "Navigate" menu and selecting "Open Type" and entering "EscapeComponent".

If Eclipse doesn't find any class by that name there's your problem.

Comment: It finds EscapeComponent. Also, verification comes out clean. There is no red underline anywhere or little red X in the icon.